# Link telephone number under Android/iOS

Tags: android, html, ios, telephony

I have links in my html page that should open a telephone call:

```
<a href="tel:1234567">Click here to call</a>
```

This works fine under iOS and older Android version. But since Android 7/8 this didn't work anymore.

Is there another, universal, way to link to telephone numbers, that work for both iOS and Android? Or is this feature completely disabled under newer Android versions?

Comment: Is this a web application you open on your phone, or a mobile application with an embedded web view?

Comment: It's in an embedded web view in a mobile application, that contains the telephone-link.